# Custom shape(rounded square) drawable android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, xml-drawable, android-shapedrawable

I want custom shape border like the one shown below:

[image]

This is what i have tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    <stroke android:width="0.1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <!--<padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" />-->
</shape>
```

But this does not give me curvy sides,only curvy corners.

> I need curvy sides

Comment: and how you are using it in your XML's button code.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/custom"

Comment: Maybe these are just images

Comment: shape will let you have a button with rounded corners, but for shapes like that one you are better off adding a background image. To my knowledge, it is not possible to achieve such a shape in xml.

Comment: Image shown above is snapshot taken from some app

Comment: is your button getting any curve by that code ?

Comment: only at corners.I have set some image as source of 'image button' and given the same button background of custom shape

Comment: then use padding and increase the value of radius.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this when change the drawable to this you will get the following output.

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rectangle" />
```

**rectangle.xml** file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

Comment: can you please help me out on this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412704/how-to-draw-a-dot-circle-inside-a-square-drawable-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412704/how-to-draw-a-dot-circle-inside-a-square-drawable-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try like this.
Create a drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="17dp" />

</shape>
```

And then use it with any view.

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"
   android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="T" />
```

Change the radious and the height and width according to your need.
Please make sure the height and width of the view must be same if you want this type of effect.